# Convert nested loop to recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I have used 3 nested loop. Now i want to convert these loops to recursive.
Also is there a general way to convert a loop into recursive?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define f(x, y, z) ((x + y) * (y + z))

int main()
{
    int test_case, p, q, r, i, j, k, a[100001], b[100001], c[100001], sum;
    scanf("%d", &test_case);
    while (test_case--) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &p, &q, &r);
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &b[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &c[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < q; i++) { // I have convert this to recursion.
            for (j = 0; j < p; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < r; k++) {
                    if (b[i] >= a[j] && b[i] >= c[k]) {
                        sum += f(a[j], b[i], c[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum % 1000000007);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A 3D loop will not be an easy thing to simply convert to recursion. To do this in a functional language I'd probably create a list of all the different index permutations, then recursively loop over the indices.

Comment: I don't see the point. Why do you want use recursion and not loop ?

Comment: @Stargateur: The nested loop take way more time and I'm trying to optimize my code. So what better way to optimize it than using recursion.

Comment: @Jeff You don't optimize code, you optimize runtime and/or memory usage. Recursion will optimize neither. Actually, it might consume more memory, especially without tail recursion. I think your loop coding is just fine.

Comment: @SHG "Actually, it might consume more memory, especially with tail recursion", without. Tail recursion will just make the function into a loop. So less memory. Contrary to recursion that could lead to stack overflow :p.

Comment: @Stargateur Right, fixed it thanks!

Comment: This is *hilarious*. You seriously believe recursion will make your algorithm magically faster? Why don't you spend a second thinking about *real* improvements?

Comment: @EOF (It's not hilarious, it's just someone less knowledgeable than you asking a valid question. There's no place for patronizing.)

Comment: @SHG Well, you'd have to drink the functional programming kool-aid pretty hard to believe recursively written C will be faster than iteratively written C for the same algorithm.

Comment: @EOF This is not the point... Do you read before answer to SHG in comment ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A loop like:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    func(i);
}
```

can be translated to recursion as:

```
void rec_fun(int i,int n) {
    if (!(i<n)) return;
    func(i);
    rec_fun(i+1,n);
}
...
rec_fun(0,n);
```

So:

```
for (i = 0; i < q; i++) { // I have convert this to recursion.
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < r; k++) {
            if (b[i] >= a[j] && b[i] >= c[k]) {
                sum += f(a[j], b[i], c[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can be translated as:

```
void rec_k(int k,int r,int i,int j) { // k-loop
    if (!(k<r)) return;
    if (b[i] >= a[j] && b[i] >= c[k]) {
        sum += f(a[j], b[i], c[k]);
    }
    rec_k(k+1,r,i,j); // recurse
}

void rec_j(int j,int p,int i,int r) { // j-loop
    if (!(j<p)) return;
    rec_k(0,r,i,j); // inner loop
    rec_j(j+1,p,i,r); // recurse
}

void rec_i(int i,int q,int p,int r) { // i-loop
    if (!(i<q)) return;
    rec_j(0,p,i,r); // inner loop
    rec_i(i+1,q,p,r); // recurse
}
...
rec_i(0,q,p,r);
```

I'm not sure this is either more readable or useful, but it meets your initial needs.

Comment: @EOF I know the point, but OP doesn't know how to translate loop to recursion, why adding more complexity... Afterall you may be right, don't know.

Comment: @EOF This is what the OP ask. More this is about coding style (If we use a compiler that optimize this into loop) and this is funny. So I think this answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the intention of this code is to only calculate the sum.

You can make a function as

```
int recurse_sum(int i, int j, int k) {
      int res = .... // Logic for calculating sum for these indices i, j, k.
      k++;
      if (k==r) {
          k = 0;
          j++;
      }
      if(j==p){
          j=0;
          i++;
      }
      if(i==q){
          return res;
      }
      return res + recurse_sum(i,j,k);
}
```

Now you can just call with `recurse_sum(0,0,0);`
The rest of the parameters can either be made global or just passed along with i,j,k.

I hope this helps.

Edit:

As mentioned by @dlasalle this code can be made open to tail call recursion optimization by placing the call at the end of the function.

In that case you can have the following version.

```
int recurse_sum(int i, int j, int k, int sum) {
      int res = .... // Logic for calculating sum for these indices i, j, k.
      k++;
      if (k==r) {
          k = 0;
          j++;
      }
      if(j==p){
          j=0;
          i++;
      }
      if(i==q){
          return res + sum;
      }
      return recurse_sum(i,j,k,res+sum);
}
```

Here the function ends with returning the value from the inner call and hence can be easily optimized.

Ofcourse in this case it will have to be called as `recurse_sum(0,0,0,0);`

Comment: I think you should point out the importance of making sure the call to `recurse_sum()` is at the end of the function (tail recursion).

Comment: @dlasalle, here actually it is not going to be a tail call since the addition is after the call and requires the `res` to be still in scope after the return from the inner call. I can make a version that is open to tail call recursion optimisations, but I wanted to keep the logic simple so it is easy for OP to follow.

Comment: @dlasalle I added another version as an edit. I hope that clears both the points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jean-Baptiste Yunès .

I made these changes to my code to convert it to recursive.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define f(x, y, z) ((x + y)*(y + z))
int sum=0;
void rec_k(int k,int r,int i,int j,int a[],int b[],int c[]) { // k-loop
    if (!(k<r)) return;
    if (b[i] >= a[j] && b[i] >= c[k]) {
        sum += f(a[j], b[i], c[k]);
    }
    rec_k(k+1,r,i,j,a,b,c);
}

void rec_j(int j,int p,int i,int r,int a[],int b[],int c[]) { // j-loop
    if (!(j<p)) return;
    rec_k(0,r,i,j,a,b,c);
    rec_j(j+1,p,i,r,a,b,c);
}

void rec_i(int i,int q,int p,int r,int a[],int b[],int c[]) { // i-loop
    if (!(i<q)) return;
    rec_j(0,p,i,r,a,b,c);
    rec_i(i+1,q,p,r,a,b,c);
}
int main() {
    int test_case, p, q, r, i, j, k, a[100001], b[100001], c[100001];
    scanf("%d", &test_case);
    while(test_case--) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &p, &q, &r);
        sum=0;
        for(i=0;i<p;i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<q;i++) {
            scanf("%d", &b[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<p;i++) {
            scanf("%d", &c[i]);
        }
        rec_i(0,q,p,r,a,b,c);
        printf("%d\n", sum%1000000007);
    }
    return 0;
}
```