# How can I make recursion switch between loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to make a Connect 4 AI which involves 7 loops nested inside each other which iterate through every possible counter position collectively. The loops all do the exact same thing apart from the last one. The loops involve breaking so the iteration can go back a step. The only issue with recursion is that I haven't figured out how to make it go back a loop, so for now that is out of the question. (I'm looking for a faster program and less lines of code.) A basic recreation of my problem is below:

```
for loop1 in range(7):
    breakChance = random.randint(1,5)
    if breakChance > 3:
        break

    for loop2 in range(7):
        breakChance = random.randint(1,5)
        if breakChance > 3:
            break
        
        for loop3 in range(7):...
```

I have tried putting the main parts of the loop in a function and sending messages to break the loop. This doesn't decrease the speed, but it does reduce the lines. I have tried using recursion, but I can't get it to do what I like: it never breaks when I want it to, and I feel it's a sacrifice of readability, to me at least.

Comment: If recursion makes your code harder to read, don't use recursion.  But if you want to break an outer loop from inside a function call, one option you might consider is exceptions, since those automatically propagate up until they're caught.  The alternative is to have each function caller check a return value and propagate it up the stack explicitly.

Comment: how about using two for loops... one for each dimension rather than 7 nested loops

Comment: Use recursion and use `return` instead of `break`: problem solved. Code repetition is a bad coding habit. One of the good practices is called DRY.

Comment: @JonSG how might i do that? i dont see how i can replace 7 loops one inside the other with only 2 loops whilst retaining the functionality? please explain in an answer, id love to see how you do it

Comment: @iCxbe, can you post a flowchart of what you want? Your indents are confusing

Comment: Why do you have seven nested loops??? There is certainly a way to simulate seven nested loops using recursion or using [`itertools.product(..., repeat=7)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but... Having seven nested loops is probably not necessary in the first place. Please explain what it is that you are trying to achieve with these seven nested loops.

Comment: *"i dont see how i can replace 7 loops one inside the other with only 2 loops whilst retaining the functionality?"*   <-- What functionality is that??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate walking a 2d board, you can do so via a pair of for loops.  You might also check out `itertools` to do it in one loop. When you find a valid counter move you exit the method with it.

```py
import random

def get_counter_position():
    for x in range(7):
        for y in range(7):
            if random.randint(1,5) > 4:
                return (x, y)
    raise Exception("No Counter Move")

print(f"Found counter move at: { get_counter_position() } ")
print(f"Found counter move at: { get_counter_position() } ")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this isnt what im after. i just need a simple example of recursion that can go back on itself.

Comment: no worries. In my mind's eye this seems to replicate what you are after, but if does not then I guess I don't quite understand what you are after.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
def my_loop(i):                                                                                                                                              
    if i==7:                                                                                                                                                 
        return                                                                                                                                               
    else:                                                                                                                                                    
        my_loop(i+1)                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                             
    for j in range(7):                                                                                                                                       
        print(f"index {j} in loop {i}")                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                             

# Run it!                                                                                                                                                             
my_loop(0)
```

Comment: this only has a depth of 2. since im utterly useless at recursion, how would i make it so theres a depth of 7?

Comment: You can translate every loop to a recursion, as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397474/convert-nested-loop-to-recursion The amount of code you'd have to write for 7 nested loops is probably not worth the obscurity of recursion though.